# How to convert an avro schema into an asyncapi programatically?

Tags: avro, asyncapi

I would like to now if exist a cli tool to convert an avro schema file into a asyncapi file.

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if such a tool exists and if it every will. The thing is that these standards are for a different purpose

**Avro**: it like a schema format that defines the structure of a message

**AsyncAPI**: it is on a higher level, it describes application behaviour and can have a lot of additional information about brokers it connects to, channels where messages are sent and consumed from.

Because **Avro** scope is limited, any CLI that would convert to AsyncAPI, would have to have some custom functionality that would enable you to provide more metadata required for the AsyncAPI document.

The good part is that you can use **Avro** inside **AsyncAPI**

Example of a message described in AsyncAPI document:

```
messages:
  userSignedUp:
    payload:
      schemaFormat: 'application/vnd.apache.avro;version=1.9.0'
      schema:
        type: record
        name: UserSignedUp
        namespace: com.company
        doc: User sign-up information
        fields:
          - name: userId
            type: int
          - name: userEmail
            type: string
```

More details in: https://www.asyncapi.com/docs/tutorials/kafka/configure-kafka-avro